# Access methods from two interfaces's implementation in a Class

Tags: java, design, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I am trying to implement the following pattern in a Cache layer.

I'm splitting the implementation of possible Cache methods such as `getUsers()` in *UserCache* Class, `getLikes()` in *PostsCache* class.

But I'd like all these methods to be accessible from a Single class object such as `Cache.getUsers()` , `Cache.getLikes()`

The reason behind this is, I'd like the developers who're using this layer to be unaware of the split that's been done behind this layer.

I've done the following

2 Interfaces - `UserCache, PostsCache` and
2 Classes implementing the interfaces - `UserCacheImpl, PostsCacheImpl`.

I tried to introduce a *abstract class* AbstractCache that implements these 2 interfaces and then this Cache class will extend that abstract class. But that failed :(

Now how can I combine these two be accessible from a single `Cache` object. Please guide me

Comment: what programming language do you use? neither question text nor tags help find it out

Comment: @gnat I've added the missed detail. It's java

Comment: This is called a Facade by the way. It harkens back to the dark ol' days of COM when you *really really really* **never** wanted to change a public interface. Today it's mostly seen in anti-corruption layers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern

Answer (score 13):

It's perfectly possible for you to have

> a[n] abstract class AbstractCache that implements these 2 interfaces and then this Cache class will extend that abstract class

```
public interface UserCache {
    int getUsers();
}

public interface PostsCache {
    int getLikes();
}

public abstract class AbstractCache implements UserCache, PostsCache {
    @Override public int getUsers() { return 12; }
    @Override public int getLikes() { return 34; }
}

public class Cache extends AbstractCache {
}
```

and that all compiles perfectly fine. What it is of course not possible to do in Java is to have multiple inheritance, where one class extends two *classes* (as opposed to implementing two interfaces), so you can't do

```
public abstract class AbstractCache extends UserCacheImpl, PostsCacheImpl {
}
```

and I suspect this is what you're actually trying to do. The solution here is **to favour composition over inheritance**:

```
public abstract class AbstractCache implements UserCache, PostsCache {
    private UserCacheImpl userCache;
    private PostsCacheImpl postsCache;

    public AbstractCache() {
        userCache = new UserCacheImpl();
        postsCache = new PostsCacheImpl();
    }

    @Override public int getUsers() { return userCache.getUsers(); }
    @Override public int getLikes() { return postsCache.getLikes(); }
}
```